# Can not login with socialmedia in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to login in me test webpage with some kind of social media on METEOR JS but when I configure it, it works but when it redirects me to the login page that's what happen:

[image: error login with social media]
[image: Error inspect]

This happened with Facebook, Google, GitHub and twitter, so... I think the problem is there.

When I try to login with my email and password works fine, the only problem is with socialmedia.

I'm using Windows 7 and WebStorm.

Maight be sometingh of my Firewall/Router configuration?

Thanks for all the help, Tony.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it, I'm trying to login in 127.0.0.1:3000 and I must enter on localhost:3000 so the security allow me to do that.